# Ansible WinRM: Unknown failure when polling update result - attempting to cancel task: pop from empty list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Linux Ubuntu 18
Ansile 2.9.27
Python 3.6
pywinrm 0.4.2 
Remote host: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

*How to fix the error pop from empty list ?*

**Ansible playbook code:**

```
   - win_updates:
       category_names:
         - CriticalUpdates
       reboot: no
       reboot_timeout: 1000
```

**Ansible console log showing Warning:**

> <1.2.3.4> Running win_updates - round 1 
> <1.2.3.4> Starting update task 
> Using module file /somewhere/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/modules/win_updates.ps1 
> Pipelining is enabled. 
> EXEC (via pipeline wrapper) 
> <1.2.3.4> Starting polling for update results 
> EXEC (via pipeline wrapper) 
> [WARNING]: Unknown failure when polling update result - attempting to cancel task: pop from empty list 
> EXEC (via pipeline wrapper) 
> EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)

**Error printed to console:**

> IndexError: pop from empty list 
> fatal: [1.2.3.4]: FAILED! => { 
> "changed": false, 
> "failed_update_count": 0, 
> "filtered_updates": {}, 
> "found_update_count": 0, 
> "installed_update_count": 0, 
> "invocation": { 
> "module_args": { 
> "accept_list": null, 
> "category_names": [ 
> "CriticalUpdates" 
> ], 
> "log_path": null, 
> "reboot": false, 
> "reboot_timeout": 1000, 
> "reject_list": null, 
> "server_selection": "default", 
> "skip_optional": false, 
> "state": "installed", 
> "use_scheduled_task": false 
> } 
> }, 
> "msg": "pop from empty list", 
> "updates": {}
> }

**Potential workaround**
The code fails in win_updates.py --> offset = int(lines.pop(-1)) , when lines is empty.  Is lines = stdout.splitlines() expected to return something always? Otherwise, we can just ignore the pop(-1) when it's empty.